# Problem with updating a vue file in a published web project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have made some changes in an installed laravel project on my server, I am not a laravel or vue developer but I changed a footer text in one of its vue files. However, the issue is after editing the file and refreshing my browser nothing has been changed!
I read some articles about it on Stackoverflow and elsewhere but all of them are talking about using nodejs commands and similar ones. I am badly confused is there any straightforward way to update the published online project with some Linux terminal commands?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have node.js installed on your server, first do you need to execute:

```
npm install
```

for install your dependencies on your project after that, you should execute

```
npm run watch
```

with this you can see the changes on your project to compile, when you want to publish the last changes to production mode, you exectute:

```
npm run prod
```

i hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

if your project directory contains all the resource files (.vue,.js) you can install node.js and compile with `npm run production`( you can see your package.json which is in the root directory, for commands to run for production)

otherwise don't compile. (make sure you backup the public directory before you compile )

in case you intend to change just a footer text  (which doesn't involve CSS or any functionality ) .. you can go to public/js/app.js and search for the current footer text and replace it with new text

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the application was build for production. If a build-tool was used, it compiled from development- to production-build. Changig the footer will then only affect the development-build, so you need to compile it afterwards.